# Remove any third party packages from former libreoffice installation

Tags: installation, package-management, libreoffice

After recent updates the global menu dissapeared as mentioned in this question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/297743/libre-office-shows-blank-menu-and-then-crashes). I tried to file a bug report by typing out

`ubuntu-bug libreoffice`

A notification Window says

> "This Problem cannot be reported. This is not an official Ubuntu
>   package. Please remove any third party packages and try again."

It occured to me that I may had a manually installed version of libreoffice. So I typed the following in terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And installed libreoffice by typing the following in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

After that, I still can't file a bug via ubuntu-bug libreoffice. I get the same message. What can I do now to get a menu in libreoffice (back). How do i remove third party packages, if I do not know them?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to remove them would be with the `synaptic` package manager. There you can group the packages by repositories, see where they belong to, and also you can check the configured software sources there. The third party packages are probably installed from some PPAs as dependencies or modules and their name didn't match with `libreoffice*`.

Comment: shouldn't `sudo apt-get autoremove` remove all dependencies or modules?

Comment: It should, if they aren't in use by any other packages on the system, but there might be shared libraries installed that were upgraded from third party source and now in use by software(s) other than libreoffice. In this case you might need to manually force the version of those packages. It's really easy to see it through with `synaptic`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that easy to see for me. I do not know how to. It seems to me, that I have completely uninstalled libreoffice and am unable to install the version ubuntu 12.04 came shipped with. Though this is a very dissapointing "experience" for me, I would like to thank you for the help you provided.